# Migrate Java Desktop Application to Android and iPhone

Tags: java, android, iphone, jquery-mobile, haxe

I have a desktop Java Application and need to migrate it to all kinds of smartphones.

Here's a short summary of what it does:

It can record human speach, save it to a wav file and send it to a webservice. The webservice can analize it send some metadata back to the client. So the application is accessing the microphone and the hdd of my computer and can communicate with other services.

I need to migrate this to android and iOS. I was looking for a solution, where I can develop once and compile the result to android and iOS. I found e.g. [haxe](http://www.haxe.org/) or [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) as cross-phone-development solutions.

The requirements for the cross-framework are the following:

- I need to be able to access the microphone
- I need to be able to record and store wav files on the phone
- I need to be able to tell the user when wlan is available for cheap data transfer
- I need to be able to send the files to webservices and wait for results *

My problem is that I cannot access the phone's microphone and storage with javaScript, or can I? Do you see a way/framework that allows me to develop once and compile everywhere? Or must I learn Objective-C and Android to accomplish what I want to do?

I'm new to this phone-development thing and would be very pleased if you could point me to the right direction.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mobile framework such as [phonegap](http://phonegap.com) which will allow you to access all the features (most of them) of the phone and then deploy the same code to multiple platforms, including android, iOS, windows phone and others.

Comment: I installed phonegap and immediately tested the microphone recordings. my problem is that I want to show the user some text that he should read while recording. currently i can only start the phone-integrated microphone app and postprocess the recorded file. Does anyone have an idea how I can start recording from within my app, without starting the integrated microphone-recording app? I need to place my own record and stop recording buttons in my app. I tried [this here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.1/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html#CaptureAudioOptions). Please help!

Comment: Forgot to answer my own follow up question.. Soltion was the Media Object. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#media.startRecord

Answer (score 1):

[AIR](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_SimpleAudioRecorder___Microphone_Access_API_AIR_2_-16746.html) might help you here. I've never tried it to such detail as to see how it accesses microphone APIs on Android and IPhone, but you can do that in Flash on the PC, so it might work for the mobile versions as well